# How to create a basic, empty, WDM driver?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, driver, wdm

I am trying to convince Visual Studio 2013 to build a driver. But never having seen Visual Studio 2013 successfully build a driver, i have no idea how to fix the problem.

So it's time to go back to the beginning. Delete the entire solution and start adding things one-by-one until it fails to build. Except i cannot get an empty solution to build.

## Let's create a [new empty WDM driver project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh454833(v=vs.85).aspx)

In Visual Studio 2013, I select:

- **File**, **New**, **Project**
- **Templates**, **Visual C++**, **Windows Drivers**, **WDM**
- **Empty WDM Driver**

And i now have a new, empty, driver solution:

[image]

Except when I attempt to build it, it fails:

> SIGNTASK : SignTool error : File not found: D:\Develop\TestDriver\MyDriver3\Win7Debug\MyDriver3.sys

Now that error isn't unexpected, there isn't even any **code** in the solution to build into a `.sys` file!

## So i'll add some code

Now let's create an empty WDM driver project, by adding an empty WDM driver file:

**Source.c**

```
#include <wdm.h>

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT object, PUNICODE_STRING registryPath)
{
   return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

And this now also fails, but this time it fails with the exact same error message as last time:

> SIGNTASK : SignTool error : File not found: D:\Develop\TestDriver\MyDriver3\Win7Debug\MyDriver3.sys

Which make sense, there is no `MyDriver3.sys` file. Not in that folder, not anywhere. There isn't a `.sys` file here, there isn't a `.sys` file there. There isn't a `.sys` file anywhere.

## How to create a basic, empty, WDM driver?

So this leaves me with the question:

> How do i create a basic, empty, WDM driver?

I'm concerned that even if Visual Studio does create a `.sys` file, it will just [fail on the next error](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/8fdfa2ae-ea62-4c9d-86e0-eabff049fe90/driver-testing-an-error-occurred-deploying-the-drivers-in-the-solution-the-system?forum=wdk). So what i'd like is a cononical example of an empty WDM solution - that builds.

## Bonus Reading

- MSDN: [Creating a New Software Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh454833(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Driver Testing an error occurred deploying the driver(s) in the solution : The system](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/8fdfa2ae-ea62-4c9d-86e0-eabff049fe90/driver-testing-an-error-occurred-deploying-the-drivers-in-the-solution-the-system?forum=wdk)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I did not use package build, but still you need:
1) go to Solutions Explorer and select Configuration Manager
2) In Configuration Manager, select the Active Solution Configuration 
In my case it was Active Solution Configuration: Win8.1 Debug
                  Active Solution Platform:      x64
That is all - just press build

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing some directives in your `inf` file that describes the name of your driver service that you want to install, or your project settings are incorrect for what you are trying to achieve.

If you do not want a driver service (typically a .sys file in kernel-mode drivers) then you need to change your project's settings for the `Configuration Type` from `Driver` to `Utility` and make sure you remove the service installation directives in your .inf file.

That's the short of it, but possibly there could be other settings in project configuration that are also incorrect.